# The command : "DELETE FROM Table where ..." doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I cannot delete some data from my table in database.

I copy some SQLite code and paste it to my new project. It is quite simple.
I correct some code and it doesn't work.

I spend lots of time to solve this problem, but I couldn't make it.

Even **no errors** have occurred.

Except for the delete query, all other queries work pretty well.

This is based on android and java.

I tried to delete data by use these queries.

```
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM mca WHERE position=" + position + ";");
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM mca WHERE _id=" + id + ";");
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM mca WHERE member='" + member + "';");
```

I made _id, position and member have same value. So this codes make sense.

_id and position are INTEGER and member is TEXT.

This is MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    MyRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;

    MemberData md;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanstState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanstState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext(), "test_alarm.db", null, 1);
        ArrayList<MemberData> member;


        member = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            try {
                md = new MemberData(member.get(member.size() - 1).position + 1, i + "");

            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("error", e+"");
                md = new MemberData(1, i+"");
            }
            member.add(md);
            dbHelper.insert(md);


        }

        /*************** activate delete command ***************/
        dbHelper.delete(2);
        /*******************************************************/

        // set up the RecyclerView
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(this, member, dbHelper);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}

class MemberData {
    public int position;
    public String member;

    public MemberData(int position, String member) {
        this.member = member;
        this.position = position;
    }
}
```

This is the SQLite function

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DBHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE mca (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, member TEXT, position INTEGER);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public void insert(MemberData md) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO mca VALUES(null, '" + md.member + "', " + md.position + ");");
        db.close();

    }

    public void delete(int position) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        /********************* Delete query *******************/
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM mca WHERE position=" + position + ";");
        /*******************************************************/

        db.close();
    }

    public ArrayList<MemberData> getData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

        ArrayList<MemberData> memberList = new ArrayList<>();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM mca", null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            memberList.add(new MemberData(cursor.getInt(1), cursor.getString(2)));
        }
        return memberList;
    }

}
```

This is the adapter for RecyclerView.

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<MemberData> mData;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ItemClickListener mClickListener;
    private DBHelper db;

    // stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView myTextView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            myTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    // data is passed into the constructor
    MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MemberData> data, DBHelper db) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mData = data;
        this.db = db;
    }

    // inflates the row layout from xml when needed
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    // binds the data to the TextView in each row
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String member = "member"+mData.get(position).member;
        holder.myTextView.setText(member);
    }

    // total number of rows
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    // convenience method for getting data at click position
    String getItem(int id) {
        return mData.get(id).member;
    }

    // allows clicks events to be caught
    void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    // parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

I just want to remove a certain value from table

Comment: "DELETE FROM ..." is not a command, it's a statement. How do you know it doesn't work? are you creating a new DB for each statement you try to run?

Comment: Google recommends you use the `delete()` method rather than `ExecSQL()`. And what does your LogCat say?

Comment: @Stultuske Thx for the language. Actually, I am a korean. i'm not used to the english. I will refer to your expression. And I used a new DB. But the results are same.

Comment: @KenY-N hmm.. I don't know what shoud I use for the LogCat. I just saw every results. And it just doesn't work.

Comment: It's a **query** - not a "querry" - one "r" is QUITE enough !

Comment: @marc_s thx. I didn't know that.

Comment: After you comment, I checked the log.
I put four data. (1, 2, 3, 4)
On the log, I can see the data have been removed from DB.
But after reboot the application, it occurs again.
I want to erase them forever.
What should I do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM mca WHERE position='" + position + "'");
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM mca WHERE _id='" + id + "'");
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM mca WHERE member='" + member + "'");
```

try this

be careful on the "'" and ";"

Comment: Actually I tried every quotation things.
It still doesn't work.

Comment: There is no error.
It is just don't remove the datas.
Hm.. how can I show you the log? this comment is quiet short to show it.

Comment: I followed your comment. 
I put four data. (1, 2, 3, 4)
On the log, I can see the data have been removed from DB.
But after reboot the application, it occurs again.
I want to erase them forever.
What should I do now?

Comment: do you have `stetho` on you app? If so, open google chrome and type `chrome://inspect/#devices`

Comment: Ok. I solved the problem.
I thought the data was indelible, but it was actually erased. And it turned out that one of the sources kept filling up the data.

It was my mistake. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Always use `'` while using a variable in SQLite queries. also remove the ";"

Eg: you have used `position` so define it like,

> ```
>  db.execSQL("DELETE FROM mca WHERE position='" + position + "'");
>  db.execSQL("DELETE FROM mca WHERE _id='" + id + "'");
>  db.execSQL("DELETE FROM mca WHERE member='" + member + "'");
> ```

Comment: Actually I tried every quotation things.
It still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you check the value of `position`, `id` and `member`?? Are you getting the values or is it empty or null?

Answer (score 1):

use db.delete it return's 0 for failure 1 for success

```
    public int delete(String position) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete("mca","position = ?",new String[] {position});
    db.close();
    }
```

Comment: make sure to clear app storage or uninstall to clear cache data of the app

Answer (score 0):

You should Change your `sql` code like below.

When you are using variable inside a `sql` query you need to bind the variable value and the `sql` query as a single string.

try the code below.

```
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM mca WHERE position='" + position + "';");
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM mca WHERE _id='" + id + "';");
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM mca WHERE member='" + member + "';");
```